# How to get the row number traversed from Mysql Table with select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made a processing application which has to process loads of data from table based on query like this..

```
Select * from table_name where column_name='';
```

Now my concern is this that suppose processing application stops suddenly in that case on restarting of the application it will start processing from the first row of the table which i dont want ..I want to ask is there any keyword in mysql by which i can get the rownumber of the table and every time it should be inserted into separate table so that on start of the application it should go to the table where row number has been stored and start processing from that row...

Any help will be welocmed.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: There isn't really a "row number" in relational databases. A table is a set of rows, not a list. The order of the rows isn't defined, and the order the rows are retrieved in can change. But you can add a row number to the table itself, if you think you need it, and order by that number.

Comment: which database are you using??

Comment: One more thing avoid using `*` unless you want to select every column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIMIT` to cut the fist *n* rows from your query result, you only have to keep track of your progress somewhere and next time your program starts you read this information and continue from there.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '' LIMIT 0,18446744073709551615
```

`0` is to fetch from the beginning of the table. To skip the first *n* rows, you just have to put the number there.

`18446744073709551615` is the maximum possible number of rows (2^64-1) in case you want to fetch them all in a single query ([MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) instructs to use this number as a method of doing that).